# Can I force quotes for STRING fields in a JobConfigurationExtract for BigQuery?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

There is a table we would like to export to a customer by means of a JobConfigurationExtract to Google Cloud Storage using Java. I encounter an issue when exchanging CSV information with a customer. The customer is forced to receive CSV files separated by a comma. String fields should always have surrounding quotes.

I noticed that, by default, no quotes are added.
I also noticed that in the query explorer, quotes are added when a delimiter is present in one of the data values.

Small snippet of code as to how we configure this job.
    `Job exportJob = new Job();
    JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = new JobConfiguration();
    JobConfigurationExtract configurationExtract = new JobConfigurationExtract();
    configurationExtract.setSourceTable(sourceTable);
    configurationExtract.setFieldDelimiter(",");
    configurationExtract.setPrintHeader(true);
    configurationExtract.setDestinationUri(destinationUri);
    //configurationExtract.setForcedQuotes(true) <=wish there was something like this.
    jobConfiguration.setExtract(configurationExtract);
    exportJob.setConfiguration(jobConfiguration);
    Bigquery bigquery = getBigQuery();
    Job resultJob = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, exportJob).execute();`

Is there a way to achieve this, without making a very complicated query that concats quotes around strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this, other than, as you suggested, writing a query that writes out string fields with quotes. However, this is a reasonable feature request. Can you file it as a feature request at the bigquery public issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/ so that we can prioritize it and you can keep track of progress?

Comment: I have done this. Thank you for your response. The issue can be found at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=167

Comment: @JordanTigani - I have an issue related to this. When I export a column which has double quotes in Big Query using jobConfiguration Extract for BiqQuery, I get two double quotes. Is there a way in configuration to supress it

Comment: those guys closed this request, did you find some workaround for this ?